# Dual boot Ubuntu/Window7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have Ubuntu installed on one hard drive and Windows 7 installed on a second hard drive. When booting into Ubuntu, the operating system sees the Windows 7 hard drive. How do I disable or unmount this hard drive so that Ubuntu ignores my Windows 7 hard drive completely everytime I boot into Ubuntu??

Comment: Are you talking about the boot menu or once you get into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You could go into your system's BIOS and disable the windows 7 hard drive, then when you run Ubuntu, run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate the GRUB configuration for the menu, minus windows, since it won't be detected.

Then, if you ever want to access the Windows drive, you would enable it in your BIOS.

It's not clear if this is your desired outcome, though.  But it will definitely "unmount" the windows drive.